# my two fragments under the same activity are shown one above the other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity:

```
public class MainActivity_with_Fragment extends RoboFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment())
                    .add(R.id.container, new AddReminderFragment())
                    //.add(R.id.container, new ReadRemindersFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

with this layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.example.stopcall.app.activities.dele_MainActivity2_with_Fragment"
             tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

I want it to host 3 fragments separately (showing only one every time):

Add `Item` to DB fragment

Read `Items` from the DB

Setting fragment

How would you suggest to design and implement this? what is the proper way?

Comment: You are adding both the fragments in same container. If you need to show only one at a time then user `replace` method not `add`. But if you need to show both at same time then add them in different containers. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding both the fragments in same container. If you need to show only one at a time do this.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   .add(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(
   .replace(R.id.container, new AddReminderFragment()).commit();
```

But if you need to show both together then create a new container (say `R.id.container_two`) and do this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container_two, new AddReminderFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: and how will i move from one fragment to the second? with one container?

Comment: ahh I see the replace. and other dynamic way to set all fragment and move between them?

Comment: This depends what are you trying to do. Try this code and see if your problem is solved.

Comment: I want to slide right and left between the fragments

Comment: You need to use Fragment pager then. See this  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: with your solution I can only alter to the first fragment again if I use "replace" one more time?

Comment: If you need to slide your fragments to left/right then this is not the approach to do it (see my  previous comment). My code gave you the solution of what you originally asked.